# Elliptical Integrals and graphing plot

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, mathematical-physics, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to computer plot the graphs of sn(u), cn(u) and dn(u) for k = 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 0.9 and 0.99

And I am trying to plot 3D graphs of sn, cn and dn as functions of u and k.

Here's what I have:

for k = 1/2:
Plot[{JacobiSN[x, .52], Sin [x]}, {x, 0, 2Pi},
PlotStyle -+ {Dashing [{O.OS, O.OS}], Dashing [{0.01, O.Ol}]}]

Can someone help generate the other graphs and provide syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a math question, or a programming question? If it';s the latter, it may be more suitable for the programming site.

Comment: It is both, but I thought to put it here since nobody I realize goes to the programming site to help

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like anyone is coming here to help, but, suit yourself.

Comment: You ask about syntax, but you also neglect to mention what language/environment you're using. Oi...